# Bash Script Unix. Pattern matching

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

How can I write the script for multiple strings in a single line with no space:

```
acgtttgggcccagctctccgccctcacacacaccccggggt
```

for visual purpose:

acg ttt ggg ccc agc tct ccg ccc tca cac aca ccc cgg ggt

and will have to match the 4th 3 letter sequence repeated 2 times. so in the above sequence we have ccc as the 4th seq. and it is repeated again after agc tct ccg.

so would I have to use grep for it?

Comment: so a solution that split your input string at every 3rd character wouldn't work? (Your sample data implies it would). If you really need rule based parsing, your sample data should show an example that matches that requirement. Good luck.

Comment: I understand that you have a DNA sequence and want to find a specific triplet...but what is the information you need to get ? Position ? number of occurence ? something else ? Is there other processing that you would need after ? and what did you try so far ?

Comment: so its going to be a file containing strings of dna sequence, and the output should be all lines that contain the triplets repeated 2 times after initial appearance after 3  other triplets. like the example given ccc appears after 3 other triplets and repeats 2 times after its first appearance

Answer (score 1):

Then how about:

```
#!/bin/bash

# add a space every three letters
str="acgtttgggcccagctctccgccctcacacacaccccggggt"
result=$(sed -e 's/\(...\)/\1 /g' <<< "$str")
echo $result

# check if the 4th sequence is repeated two times
awk '
{   ref = $4;                       # set the 4th sequence as a reference
    for (i=5; i<=NF; i++)           # iterate from 5th sequence to the end
        if (ref == $i) count++      # count the same one as the reference
    printf "4th sequence \"%s\" repeated %d times.\n", ref, count
}' <<< "$result"
```

which yields:

```
acg ttt ggg ccc agc tct ccg ccc tca cac aca ccc cgg ggt
4th sequence "ccc" repeated 2 times.
```

The script is composed of two parts: 1st one to split the string with spaces, and the 2nd one to count the repetition of the 4th triplet.

- The `sed` script `sed -e 's/\(...\)/\1 /g'` inserts a space after every three letters.
- The `awk` script loops over the sequences for the one which is same as the 4th triplet.
- If you just want to make sure the repetition is exactly *two* times or not, you may modify the script to compare `count` with 2.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to split the string with line-feeds `'s/\(...\)/\1\n/g'` or simply `grep -o ...`?

Comment: Good suggestion. Splitting into lines instead of columns will make the following process easier with line-oriented commands like `head`. On the other hand, applying `grep -o` *without* breaking the string into triplets may match with letters regardless of the punctuations.

Comment: The`grep -o '...'`was meant as a alternative way to break the string into triplets. Only difference to `sed 's/\(...\)/\1\n/g'` (as long as the input length is a multiple of 3) is that it omits the additional linefeed at the end.

Comment: All right, understood. Thank you for your courtesy.